# How to connect from one server to another server`s postgresql database by configuring firewall

Tags: postgresql, firewall, iptables, gentoo

I am trying to connect from Ubuntu 16.04 server to Gentoo server`s Postgresql database. But i cannot connect to it. Ubuntu server has internet with static **Ip: 93.154.53.88**.  In my Gentoo server has **Ip: 192.168.0.104**. I configured my **pg_hba.conf** also to Ip address of Ubuntu server. But anyway it cannot connect to it. My **pg_hba.conf** is like below:

```
host    all             all             93.154.52.85/32           trust
host    all             all             93.154.53.88/32           md5
```

When i ping to my Gentoo Server like below it is **not going**. I think I should configure some firewall settings.

```
ping 93.154.53.88
```

But When i connected my Gentoo Server`s database from **second Linux server** it can connect which has Ip address: **93.154.52.85**. But Ubuntu server cannot connect to it. I read some post in which iptables need to be configured Please Help me What to configure and how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can’t ping the Gentoo server, then it sounds like a networking issue. You can ping Gentoo from `x.x.52.x` but not from `x.x.53.x` — sounds like a subnetting problem?

Comment: Yes it i am giving ping from x.x.52.x . In question ip addresses are changed.